# Can't fetch data or parse html from web sites in Flutter

Tags: html, flutter, http, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am tring to do some web srawing in flutter but there is some unknown bugs.

**I have tried two ways for this. First one is sending HTTP get request to site:**

```
  void makeRequest() async {
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.http("www.koeri.boun.edu.tr", 'scripts/lst0.asp'));
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String htmlToParse = response.body;
      print(htmlToParse);
    }
  }
```

It only gets header of page

```
I/flutter (13484): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254">
I/flutter (13484): <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="tr">
I/flutter (13484):
I/flutter (13484): <head>
I/flutter (13484):
I/flutter (13484): <title>Son Depremler</title>
I/flutter (13484): </head>
I/flutter (13484): <!--- <link rel=stylesheet href="ccm.css" type=text/css> --->
I/flutter (13484): <BODY bgColor=Ivory>
I/flutter (13484):
I/flutter (13484): <Table Border=0 align=center cellspacing=1 width=80%>
I/flutter (13484): <tr>
I/flutter (13484):
I/flutter (13484):  <td>
```

**Second way I have tried is using WebScraper**

```
initiate() async {
    final webScraper = WebScraper('http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr');
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> elements;
    if (await webScraper.loadWebPage('/scripts/lst0.asp')) {
      elements = webScraper.getElement('pre', ['text']);
    }
    for (var item in elements) {
      print(item);
    }
  }
```

That returns only a few lines of body of the internet site

```
I/flutter (13484): {title: ..................TÜRKÝYE VE YAKIN ÇEVRESÝNDEKÝ SON DEPREMLER....................
I/flutter (13484): .....BÖLGESEL DEPREM-TSUNAMÝ ÝZLEME VE DEÐERLENDÝRME MERKEZÝ HIZLI ÇÖZÜMLERÝ.....
I/flutter (13484): ......(YAPAY SARSINTI ANALÝZÝ YAPILMAMIÞTIR) Son 500 deprem listelenmiþtir......
I/flutter (13484):                                                         Büyüklük
I/flutter (13484): Tarih      Saat      Enlem(N)  Boylam(E) Derinlik(km)  MD   ML   Mw    Yer                                             Çözüm Niteliði
I/flutter (13484): ---------- --------  --------  -------   ----------    ------------    --------------                                  --------------
I/flutter (13484): 2021.04.15 23:42:17  36.4522   27.1423        5.4      -.-  1.7  -.-   ONIKI ADALAR (AKDENIZ)                            Ýlksel
I/flutter (13484): 2021.04.15 23:28:39  36.3872   27.1992        6.5      -.-  1.9  -.-   ONIKI ADALAR (AKDENIZ)                            Ýlksel
I/flutter (13484): 2021.04.15 23:22:49  40.6805   33.3555        8.2      -.-  2.0  -.-   CUKUROREN-KORGUN (CANKIRI)                        Ýlksel
I/flutter (13484): 2021.04.15 23:10:56  36.
```

**[This is](http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/scripts/lst0.asp) the site I want to get.**

Comment: It seems like you are getting the response correctly, but maybe it is not printing the whole thing? Try checking the length of your item (in the second element) and see what it is (perhaps you are having encoding issues, or similar).

Comment: No it only takes 2 elements :(

Comment: I looked at the HTML in the page and there is only one `pre` element in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print method does not allow you to print more than x characters! So when you need to print lots of data to your console, consider using debugPrint or even making use of a Text widget to display it!

Comment: Thank you very much I didn' know that.